# Unable to install dns with pip after upgrading pip

Tags: python, macos, pip

Log speaks for itself. I ran pip and it said I needed to upgrade it, so I did. Now I still can't install dns.

```
~/electrum/python electrum
Error: No module named 'dns'. Try 'sudo pip install <module-name>'
~/electrum/pip install dns
Collecting dns
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dns (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dns
~/electrum/git log
commit c8e67e2bd07efe042703bc1368d499c5e555f854 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: ThomasV <thomasv@electrum.org>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you need "dnspython" package, which is imported by "dns" name that's why you getting *No module named 'dns'* message :) Try this

```
pip install dnspython
```